# how to specify fdt_file in an U-boot build with Yocto

Tags: yocto, u-boot, bitbake

How can I specify the value of the variable 'fdt_file' in U-Boot that is build with Yocto?
Is UBOOT_CONFIG="fdt_file=test.dtb" in the local.conf the solution?  It didn't work.  Our do I have to create a patch file to apply to set in C this variable.  Or would the Uenv.txt file be a solution?

Answer (score 2):

> Is UBOOT_CONFIG="fdt_file=test.dtb" in the local.conf the solution?

No, this is incorrect. `UBOOT_CONFIG` specify configuration file name (without extension) what should be used to build u-boot. Configuration files located under `include/configs` inside u-boot src dir.

> Our do I have to create a patch file to apply to set in C this variable.

Yes. There is `CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS` variable (located inside board config file) what define default values for environment variables. You can append `"fdt_file=test.dtb\0"` to it (don't forget `\0` at the end). As another solution, you can set it value using `setenv("fdt_file", "test.dtb")` somewhere during board initialization.

> Or would the Uenv.txt file be a solution?

Yes.

Pick one solution what better match your needs. For example, modifying `uEnv.txt` is simpler, because you don't need to rebuild u-boot every time. But have hardcoded value inside u-boot may be useful in some situations.